# How to do if with multiple rows in PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables like this

```
Table: creation date

ID       user          create date
1         ABC         Jan 1, 2021
2         EFC         Feb 1, 2021
3         HIJ         Feb 1, 2021
1         ABC         Feb 1, 2021
1         ABC         Feb 20, 2021
```

And a log of blocking

```
ID        user        blocked from     blocked till
1          ABC         Jan 20, 2021     Feb 10, 2021 
3          HIJ         Jan 5, 2021      Jan 10, 2021
1          ABC         Feb 25, 2021     Mar 10, 2021
```

As you can see the relationship between the tables are Many to Many. What I wanted to check is if the create date is during the blocked date in the log.

If it was ONE to MANY relationship, I could have used

```
Yes or No = IF(AND(creation date < RELATED(log[blocked from]), creation date > RELATED(log[blocked till])), "Yes", "No")
```

But now as there are multiple rows for the same ID how can I just check if the creation date is between any of the blocked from and Blocked till date?

Comment: Is it possible to have an overlap of `blocked from` and `blocked till` range per ID? Meaning for ID1 the first range is `from 2021-1-20 to 2021-2-10` and the next range is `from 2021-2-25 to 2021-3-10`. Is it also possible that the data contains another overlapping range for the same ID such as `from 2021-01-05 to 2021-01-07`. All dates are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: No it wont overlap

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a measure like this

```
Measure2 =
VAR _maxID =
    MAX ( creationDate[ID] )
VAR _minBlockedFrom =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( blockLog[blocked from] ),
        FILTER ( VALUES ( blockLog[ID] ), blockLog[ID] = _maxID )
    )
VAR _maxBlockedTill =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( blockLog[blocked till] ),
        FILTER ( VALUES ( blockLog[ID] ), blockLog[ID] = _maxID )
    )
VAR _maxDate =
    MAX ( creationDate[create date] )
RETURN
    IF ( _maxDate >= _minBlockedFrom && _maxDate <= _maxBlockedTill, "Yes", "No" )
```

[image: S1]

**`Edit`**

please use a measure like this

```
Measure3 =
MAXX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            CROSSJOIN (
                SELECTCOLUMNS (
                    creationDate,
                    "_id", creationDate[ID],
                    "_user", creationDate[user],
                    "_date", creationDate[create date]
                ),
                blockLog
            ),
            [_user] = [user]
        ),
        "condition",
            IF ( [_date] >= [blocked from] && [_date] <= [blocked till], "Yes", "No" )
    ),
    [condition]
)
```

[image: S1]

Comment: This is incorrect. Feb 20, 2021 ABC entry is not in any blocked period.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Measure** as below-

```
is_from_block_range = 

var current_row_id = min('CreationDate'[ID])
var current_row_user = min('CreationDate'[user])
var creation_date = min('CreationDate'[create date])
var chk_macth = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        all('BlockLog'),
        'BlockLog'[ID] = current_row_id
            && 'BlockLog'[user] = current_row_user
            && 'BlockLog'[blocked from] <= creation_date
            && 'BlockLog'[blocked till] >= creation_date
    )
)

return if(chk_macth >=1, "Yes", "No")
```

Output will be as below-

[image]